# Which would be wise to do: enforcing HTTPS at IIS level or enforcing HTTPS through web.config settings?

Tags: iis-7, https

All,

I have a need to secure my web application over SSL. I have couple of options

1. Enable HTTPS connecting using configuration through web.config.
2. Enable HTTPS settings through IIS (security).

But I am in a dilemma to decide on a wise option among the two. I am not aware if there are any more options other than the 2 (barring the URL redirect option).

Please suggest which option could be preferred and why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

All,

I believe this question is irrelevant in the Context of WCF Web Services where the HTTPS needs to be enabled  both at the IIS level using 'Add Binding feature' as well as configuring security tag to Transport with relevant clientCredentialType.

`<bindings>
   <webHttpBinding>
       <binding name="webBind" bypassProxyOnLocal="true">
           <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
           </security>
       </binding>
   </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>`

PS: I am sorry for the formatting part as I am not able to crack it.